# Como pegar um checkbox multidimensional clicado

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Tenho um grupo de checkbox e preciso pegar o checkbox que o usuário clicou, com isso, preciso manipular os outros que sejam do mesmo grupo.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[1][1][]" value="A" data-unique="0"> A
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[1][2][]" value="B" data-unique="0"> B
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[1][3][]" value="C" data-unique="0"> C
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[1][4][]" value="D" data-unique="1"> D

<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[2][1][]" value="A" data-unique="0"> A
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[2][2][]" value="B" data-unique="0"> B
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[2][3][]" value="C" data-unique="0"> C
<input type="checkbox" name="grupo[2][4][]" value="D" data-unique="1"> D
```

Em outra listagem de checkbox que tenho fiz assim:

```
$('input[name="grupo[]"]').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var is_unique = $this.data('unique');
    var is_checked = $this.is(':checked');
    var grupo = $('input[name="grupo[]"]');

    if(is_unique == '1') {

        grupo.each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            $(this).prop("disabled", is_checked);

            $this.prop("checked", is_checked);
            $this.prop("disabled", false);

        });
    }
});
```

Só que nessa minha nova listagem eu tenho esse array multidimensional e dessa forma não funciona, será que alguém tem alguma dica para me ajudar?

Comment: Tente mudar `$('input[name="grupo[]"]')` para `$('input[name^="grupo["]')` e vê se isso resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Não funcionou não. Não sei bem o que é o `^` e outra, acho que dessa forma não irá pegar o grupo que preciso ainda manipular `grupo[x][y][]`

Comment: o ^ é pra dizer um name que começa com grupo[, no caso ele deveria pegar todos os elementos com esse nome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que não utilizar classes?

```js
$('.grupo').click(function() {
    
    var $this = $(this);
    var is_unique = $this.data('unique');    
    var is_checked = $this.is(':checked');
    var grupo = $this.data('group');
    
    if(is_unique == '1') {        
        $('.grupo').each(function() {
            var grupoAtual = $(this).data('group');
            if(grupoAtual != grupo)
                return;
            
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            $(this).prop("disabled", is_checked);

            $this.prop("checked", is_checked);
            $this.prop("disabled", false);

        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[1][1][]" data-group="1" value="A" data-unique="0"> A
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[1][2][]" data-group="1" value="B" data-unique="0"> B
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[1][3][]" data-group="1" value="C" data-unique="0"> C
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[1][4][]" data-group="1" value="D" data-unique="1"> D

<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[2][1][]" data-group="2" value="A" data-unique="0"> A
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[2][2][]" data-group="2" value="B" data-unique="0"> B
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[2][3][]" data-group="2" value="C" data-unique="0"> C
<input type="checkbox" class="grupo" name="grupo[2][4][]" data-group="2" value="D" data-unique="1"> D
```

Comment: Não estou fazendo assim, primeiro por causa de que já esta pronto o salvar no lado do servidor e não posso mudar essa parte nessa altura do campeonato, e outra, como eu saberia qual valor é de qual grupo.

Comment: Alterei o código acima, mantendo as propriedades `name` como estavam, ou seja, mantendo o código para salvar no servidor. Clique em "Executar trecho de código" e verá que o lado cliente está funcionando também. Acredito que essa solução já te atende.

Comment: Funcionou sim.. Faltou eu abrir um pouco a mente para o que tinha passado.. Valew